# How to remove a particular word in an Excel cell?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, worksheet-function

How do you remove a particular word in a column of one cell that's in another cell in Excel.

Example: if

- A1 = `*1603 Ad street New York*`,
- B1 = `*New York*`
- then in C1 I want = `*1603 Ad street*`

Answer (score 14):

Use the Substitute function:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,B1,"")
```

EDIT: Per brettdj's suggestion, added TRIM to get rid of leading or trailing spaces:

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,B1,""))
```

Comment: Is there a way to improve this solution and allow it to accept a range instead of `B1`? Like a list of words I want to remove from the cell `A1`!!

Answer (score 3):

Just use the Replace function. leave " replace with" blank

Comment: Maybe a little more detail would help the users

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula for range of words:

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,INDEX($B$1:$B$56,IF(ISNA(MATCH(FALSE,ISERR(FIND($B$1:$B$56,A1)),FALSE)),0,MATCH(FALSE,ISERR(FIND($B$1:$B$56,A1)),FALSE)),1),""))
```