# Find duplicate text in a string and remove it

Tags: excel, match, trim, vlookup, duplicate-data

I have this excel problem. I am trying to find matching text between 2 columns and then remove the matched text. Example

Column 1:

```
John Romeo
```

Column 2:

```
John Romeo 16 Smith Street
```

Results:

```
16 Smith Street
```

The Results column is the text that I want.

Comment: Use the `SUBSTITUTE` function.

Comment: Here's an answer I gave on `SUBSTITUTE`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6209927/293078. In addition, you can easily find info on the web.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a custom function called WORDDIF that may do what you want.

To install the custom function in Windows ...
Alt+F11 to open the VBA Editor
From the VBA menu, select Insert -> Module

To install the custom function in OS X ...
Go to Tools -> Macro -> Visual Basic Editor
From the VBA menu, select Insert -> Module

Paste the code below in the VBA Edit window

Back in Excel, copy this formula into your Results column:

Results=WORDDIF(Column1Cell1, Column2Cell2)

```
Function WORDDIF(rngA As Range, rngB As Range) As String

Dim WordsA As Variant, WordsB As Variant
Dim ndxA As Long, ndxB As Long, strTemp As String

WordsA = Split(rngA.Text, " ")
WordsB = Split(rngB.Text, " ")

For ndxB = LBound(WordsB) To UBound(WordsB)
    For ndxA = LBound(WordsA) To UBound(WordsA)
        If StrComp(WordsA(ndxA), WordsB(ndxB), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            WordsA(ndxA) = vbNullString
            Exit For
        End If
    Next ndxA
Next ndxB

For ndxA = LBound(WordsA) To UBound(WordsA)
    If WordsA(ndxA) <> vbNullString Then strTemp = strTemp & WordsA(ndxA) & " "
Next ndxA

WORDDIF = Trim(strTemp)

End Function
```

For attribution, the solution is from http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/486708-compare-two-strings-find-difference.html

Comment: Thanks. But it didnt work for me. I am reading the forum and couldn;t find anything yet.

Comment: Why would they need a UDF when the built-in `SUBSTITUTE` and `REPLACE` functions already do this?

Comment: Hey Doug
Do you mind showing me the way to use substitute?
Cheers