# Compare two string values and return the common string

Tags: excel, function, match, string-comparison

This is what I would like to do in Excel.

A1 = Hello my name is John
B1 = Hello my name is Joe

C1 = Hello my name is

A2 = Where is John going out tomorrow?
B2 = Where is Joe going out tomorrow?

C1 = Where is

As you can see, I want to compare 2 cells and return the common string  until there is a difference. (Stop the comparison as soon there is a change)

I have seen something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22950762/find-duplicate-text-in-a-string-and-remove-it) but is it slightly different from my request.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: -1 because you have not shown any effort to solve the task yourself.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not an expert at this and hence resorting to posting to this forum. In fact this is my first post ever online for help :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should search for a more efficient way but here's one in VBA:

```
Dim stringA As String
Dim stringB As String

Dim finalString As String

Dim currentLetter As Integer

For currentLetter = 0 To Len(stringA)
    If Left(stringA, currentLetter) = Left(stringB, currentLetter) Then
        finalString = Left(stringA, currentLetter)
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Replace the string variables by your cells and it's done.

Comment: shouldn't it be: `If Left(stringA, currentLetter) <> Left(stringB, currentLetter) Then` stop everything

Answer (score 0):

I liked the challenge, so here is a formula solution I came up with:

```
=LEFT(A1,LOOKUP(2,1/(MID(LEFT(A1,MATCH(FALSE,INDEX(MID(A1,ROW($1:$99),1)=MID(B1,ROW($1:$99),1),),0)-1),ROW($1:$99),1)=" "),ROW($1:$99))-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer that was here was fine, only one thing was wrong (at least for me). I can't comment so I am pasting the solution here with my fix. "***Exit for***" was not needed:

```
Dim stringA As String
Dim stringB As String

Dim finalString As String

Dim currentLetter As Integer

For currentLetter = 0 To Len(stringA)
    If Left(stringA, currentLetter) = Left(stringB, currentLetter) Then
        finalString = Left(stringA, currentLetter)            
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub CommonText()
    'Finds the longest substring that string A and string B have in common.

    sA = "Hey, My Name is John"
    sB = "My Name is Eric"

    Dim iLtrA As Integer

    Dim iLtrB As Integer
    Dim sThisString As String
    Dim sFinalString As String

    sFinalString = ""

    For iLtrA = 1 To Len(sA)

        For iLtrB = 1 To Len(sB)

            For n = 1 To Application.Min(Len(sA), Len(sB))
                'mid(text,start, length)
                If Mid(sA, iLtrA, n) = Mid(sB, iLtrB, n) Then
                    sThisString = Mid(sA, iLtrA, n)
                    If Len(sThisString) >= Len(sFinalString) Then
                        sFinalString = sThisString
                    End If
                End If
            Next n
        Next iLtrB
    Next iLtrA

    Debug.Print sFinalString

End Sub
```